# Python: Get the longest matching keyword mentions in text

Tags: python, nlp

I have a list of keywords including their variations that I search in text like :

```
keywords = ['US Dollar', 'Australian Dollar', 'Dollar', 'Dollars']
```

and I want to look up these keywords in texts like :

> 'Dollar News: The Australian Dollar slumped in the face of a recovering US Dollar'

and get the most comprhensive matches (i.e. longest) which are 'Dollar' in the beginning of the sentence, and 'Australian Dollar' and 'US Dollar'(and not 'Dollar' in those cases for instance).

I have so far tried this:

```
keywords.sort(key = len, reverse=True)

first = lambda text, kws: next((k for k in kws if k in text), None)

first(myText, keywords)
```

which returns 'Australian Dollar' as it is the longest match. How can I get other matches (here, 'Dollar' in 'Dollar News...' and 'US Dollar') as well?

Comment: longest match can be only one right, since Australian Dollar and US Dollar are of different length

Comment: This seems like NLP problem

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Longest match and two results?
I think it's not a good design. Create your design first and then regex/logic for it.

Comment: Based on my understanding, you want to exclude `Dollar` as a keyword since it is part of a longer keyword (`Australian Dollar` / `US Dollar`). Why not just restructure the keywords list (so all of them are desirable) and get all matches? Your current code returns only the longest match from that generator.

Comment: I want to keep 'Dollar' in the keywords list for cases no longer keyword is available.

Comment: The list of keywords in `keywords` are the only keywords you are after? Or if there are other keywords, what is a general rule to exclude "shorter" keywords? Is it something @TheGamer007 mentioned?

Comment: @Unni I want to recover 'Dollar' too if it is not in other forms (i.e. 'US Dollar', etc.)

Comment: I am still not clear if you are looking for only the keywords `['US Dollar', 'Australian Dollar', 'Dollar', 'Dollars']` in the string. This is important because if you don't have an arbitrary number of keywords other than these 4, the solution is a lot easier.

Comment: @Unni it can be further extended to include bunch of other currencies.

Comment: One possibility would be to use a suffix-tree (https://github.com/ptrus/suffix-trees). Get the position of every keyword as a list of integer ranges, and remove overlapped  ranges.

Comment: @EricDuminil Suffix trees did the job! I had to add spaces to the beginings and the ends of the keywords to avoid mismatches like "petrodollar", etc. Thanks!

Comment: @Chappleton great! You're allowed to write an answer yourself, in order to help people having the same problem as you in the future.

Comment: Have you tried Using a Named Entity Recognition tool like the one in SpaCy and NLTK? Look here to know more in Spacy: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features/ - Noun Chunks might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use suffix trees to get the positions of every keyword mention and then handle the overlapping as suggested by @EricDuminil .

Here is my function for extracting keywords' `kws` positions in text source `txt`:

```
from suffix_trees import STree

def findMentions(txt, kws):

    st = STree.STree(txt)
    spans = []

    for kw in kws:
        starts = st.find_all(kw)
        spans.extend([(item, item+len(kw)) for item in starts])

    bounds = handleOverlap(spans)

    return bounds
```

and here is the function to handle overlapping character positions:

```
def handleOverlap(spans):
    del_in = []
    for x in spans:
        if spans.index(x) in del_in: continue
        for y in spans:
            if spans.index(y) in del_in: continue
            if x == y: continue
            if len(set(list(range(x[0],x[1]+1))) & set(list(range(y[0],y[1]+1)))) > 0:
                if len(list(range(x[0],x[1]+1))) > len(list(range(y[0],y[1]+1))):
                    del_in.append(spans.index(y))
                    spans.pop(spans.index(y))
                elif len(list(range(y[0],y[1]+1))) > len(list(range(x[0],x[1]+1))):
                    del_in.append(spans.index(x))
                    spans.pop(spans.index(x))
    return spans
```

I just had to add spaces to the both ends of each keyword to avoid getting words containing a keyword, like 'petrodollar'. The results are the non-overlapping start and end positions for the longest corresponding mentioned keywords.

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Jun 13 14:21:59 2019

@author: jainil
"""
keywords = ['US Dollar', 'Australian Dollar', 'Dollar', 'Dollars']
keywords.sort(key = len, reverse=True)
keywords

text='The Australian Dollar slumped in the face of a recovering US Dollar'
dictt={}
for i in keywords:
    dictt[i]=text.count(i)

max_len=0
max_value=0
for i in dictt.keys():
    if len(i.split())>max_len and dictt[i]>0:
        max_len= len(i.split())
        if(dictt[i]>max_value):
            max_value=dictt[i]



for i,j in dictt.items():
    if(len(i.split())==max_len and j==max_value):
        print(i,j)
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it cannot retrieve "Dollar" if it is not accompaned by an adjective. See the updated question and the selected answer.